# Подгон анимации перемещения под разные разрешения

Tags: java, android, android-animation

Как можно подогнать анимацию перемещения, к примеру по Y, чтобы под разными разрешениями объект перемешался одинаково. Вот, к примеру, код анимации, на разрешении 1920 все идеально, а на 720 анимация улетает слишком высоко от нужного положения.

```
final ObjectAnimator moveAnimBar = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(EditImageBar, "Y",metricsB.heightPixels,metricsB.heightPixels - 350);
    moveAnimBar.setDuration(500);

    ObjectAnimator moveAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(BottomBar, "Y", metricsB.heightPixels - 150);
    moveAnim.setDuration(500);
    moveAnim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

            //EditImageBar.setEnabled(true);
            //EditImageBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            moveAnimBar.start();
        }
    });

    moveAnim.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте смещения в dp, а в пиксели преобразуйте например так:

```
float pxValue = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dpValue, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```